# form.validate_on_submit() from flask_wtf FlaskForm not working

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I am trying to submit a form using wtforms. I can't get it to validate. I also tried using `{{ form.csrf_token }}` and it still did not work.

```py
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisthesecretkey'
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[
                           InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[
                             InputRequired(), Length(min=8, max=80)])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember me')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = forms.LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'worked'

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

my jinja:

```
        <form class="form-signin" action="/login" method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.username) }}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.remember_me) }}
        </form>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted text-center">© 2020</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `action` dictates the form will post to `/login`. I think you want `action="/register"`

Comment: Oh, my bad... I actually copied the wrong part of the code, I now fixed it, but still get the same error

Comment: Ok, if you don't get any exceptions, can you look at/output `form.errors`?

Comment: I don't even know how to do that, I placed `{{ form.errors }}` after the <form></form> in the 'login.html' file, so I get to see it in the website, but it just shows up as:
`{}`

Comment: Have a try with `{{ form.username() }}` etc in your Jinja. I've not used `.form_field` myself so unsure if this is an issue

Comment: I just wanna try one more thing before I give up on this method, is there a way to check errors on validation?

Comment: Try add a `print(form.errors)` after the validate_on_submit (i.e. else) to see if it is a validation failure

Comment: nothing shows up, I also noticed that <button> was outside the form, I placed it inside, but same error, only difference is that now the page refreshes when I click it

Comment: I also tried using `{{ form.username() }}`, but I keep getting nothing out of `.validate_on_submit()`

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the form class or action?

Comment: I solved it and answered the post! Check it out if you wish to

Answer (score 0):

I had an  and  before the form, I placed them inside  and then added a  to the form fields, this solved the issue, it now looks like this:

```html
<form class="form-signin-heading"  method="POST" action="/login">
        <div class="text-center mb-4">
            <img class="mb-4" src="/static/logo.jpg" width="72" height="72">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Heading1</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```